# How to show UICollectionView with first section on left side and second section right side of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I want to create a UICollectionView with its first section on the left side of the screen a second section right side of the screens like two columns. For each section, I need a section header.
Is there any way achieve this or any alternative way.[image]

Comment: I think if you make your items width as collectionViewwidth/2 you can put your elements of section1 in pairs indexpath.row and for secction 2 for odds indexPath.row

Comment: you may use custom layout.

Comment: @ReinierMelian Actually I need it like this- I have updated the question with an image.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.data = @[@[[UIColor blackColor],[UIColor blackColor],[UIColor blackColor]],        //section 1
                  @[[UIColor yellowColor],[UIColor yellowColor],[UIColor yellowColor]]];    //section 2

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [self.collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)];
    [self setupCollectionViewCellSize];
}

- (void)setupCollectionViewCellSize {
    int numOfCell = 2, paddingBetweenCell = 8;
    float width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - (self.collectionView.contentInset.left + self.collectionView.contentInset.right);   //minus left and right Inset
    float cellWidth = (width - (numOfCell * paddingBetweenCell)) / numOfCell;
    self.cellSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return self.cellSize;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.data objectAtIndex:0] count] + [[self.data objectAtIndex:1] count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(indexPath.item%2==0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [[self.data objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex: (indexPath.item%[[self.data objectAtIndex:0] count])];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [[self.data objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex: (indexPath.item%[[self.data objectAtIndex:1] count])];
    }
    return cell;
}
```